# NoReverseMatch ... and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, templating

I'm new to django. I've tried the tutorial so many times. I now have started my own project until I am faced with NoReverseMatch ... and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

**my template** section_list.html

```
{% for section in section_name %}
    <a href='{% url 'employee_listings' hsection section %}' >
       {{ section }}

 </br>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^letters/(?P<employee_id>\d+)$', views.letters, name='letters'),    
    url(r'(?P<word>\d+)/$', views.headsection_listings, name='headsection_listings'),
    url(r'(?P<hsection>\w+)$', views.section_listings, name='section_listings'),
    url(r'(?P<hsection>\w+)/(?P<section>\w+)/$', views.employee_listings, name='employee_listings'),
    )
```

**views.py**

```
def employee_listings(request, hsection, section):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    employee_list = Employee.objects.all()
    employee_id = [p.emp_id for p in employee_list if p.section.section_name == section]
    employee_name = [p.emp_first_name +' ' +  p.emp_last_name for p in employee_list if p.section.section_name == section]
    #    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    context = {'employee_name':employee_name, 'section':section, 'employee_id':employee_id}
    return render(request, 'kapra/employee_list.html', context)

def section_listings(request, hsection):
    section_list = Section.objects.all()
#    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    section_name = [p.section_name for p in section_list if p.headsection.head_section_name == hsection]
    context = {'section_name':section_name, 'hsection':hsection}
    return render(request, 'kapra/section_list.html', context)
```

**Browser Output:**
    NoReverseMatch at /kapra/Administration

```
Reverse for 'section_listings' with arguments '(u'Administration', u'Employee Admin')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
.... Reverse for 'section_listings' with arguments '(u'Administration', u'Employee Admin')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried:[]
```

django_version 1.6.11 
if I don't use {% url %} and use {/kapra/...} format it works.

Comment: section_listing is expecting only 1 keyword it seems.

Comment: Sorry, I posted irrevalent view at first, its edited now. The view section_listings is not being matched actually.

Comment: You are trying to solve an url that does not exist. maybe try {% url 'employee_listings' hsection section %}

Comment: Or update your url for section_listing to receive 2 keywords, not 1.

Comment: I'm sorry for the error. I actually tried {% url 'employee_listings' hsection section %}  the error is Reverse for 'employee_listings' with arguments '(u'Administration', u'Employee Admin')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Do you really mean to be passing `(u'Administration', u'Employee Admin')` to `{% url %}`? Is the space intended? You expect the URL to be `/Administration/Employee Admin/`?

Comment: yes, indeed. the NoReverseMatch error comes in every other views as well, the other format though works everywhere. I've tried the namespace, 'kapra:employee_listings'  as namespace in project urls.py is 'kapra'. Its the problem with matching reverse

Comment: Does my answer work now?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm reviewing my code again.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two arguments besides the URL name to `{% url ... %}`:

```
{% url 'section_listings' hsection section %}
```

However, both your `urls.py` and `views.py` suggest you should only pass one extra argument:

```
# urls.py
url(r'(?P<hsection>\w+)$', views.section_listings, name='section_listings'),
# views.py:
def section_listings(request, section):
```

Try this instead in your template:

```
{% url 'section_listings' hsection %}
```

or, since you have a named argument in your url, you can use:

```
{% url 'section_listings' hsection=hsection %}
```

Comment: {% for hsection in head_section_name %}
    <a href='/kapra/{{ hsection }}'>{{ hsection }}
</br> 
{% endfor %} 
... this works but
<a href='{% url 'employee_listings' hsection section %}' > {{ section }} </br> does not.

Comment: I'm confused now. You just changed your question to say it is a different problem. So is section_listing working or not?

Comment: I'm in fedora 21, the <a href='{% url 'employee_listings' hsection section %}' > , .... ,  url(r'(?P<hsection>\w+)/(?P<section>\w+)/$', views.employee_listings, name='employee_listings'),....., def employee_listings(request, hsection, section): ... have not been working.

Comment: Did you try this: `{% url 'section_listings' hsection=hsection %}` or `{% url 'employee_listings' hsection=hsection section=section %}`?

Comment: Are you sure that `section` and `hsection` are what you expect they are? What about passing actual strings that you know for certain should work?

Comment: How do I pass actual string? (u'Administration', u'Employee Admin') where they are hsection=Administration section=Employee Admin

Comment: Actually, other views are not working too in this regard.

Comment: Well, your regex is `r'(?P<hsection>\w+)/(?P<section>\w+)/$'` and you are using `'Employee Admin'` for section. There is no way for that to match `\w+`, since `\w+` means 1 or more 'word' characters such as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. You have a space and `\w` won't match a space.

Comment: What do I do to include space? Please improve my regex for space inclusion.

Comment: Well, `[\w\s]+` would let you have a space, but you really shouldn't be using URLs with spaces. Maybe you want to be using a slug field instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one slash at the end of the URL you are calling:

```
/kapra/Administration
```

should be

```
/kapra/Administration/
```

Consider manipulating your pattern to allow to omit the slash:

```
url(r'(?P<hsection>\w+)/(?P<section>\w+)/?$', views.employee_listings, name='employee_listings'),
```

Note the `?` after the last slash
According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for `url`,you are passing `args` when you should pass `kwargs`. Try passing `kwargs`:

```
{% for section in section_name %}
    <a href='{% url 'employee_listings' hsection=hsection section=section %}' >
       {{ section }}
     </br>
{% endfor %}
```

---

**Explanation:**

You may pass args to a pattern like this:

```
url(r'^client/([0-9]+)/$', app_views.client, name='app-views-client')
```

But only kwargs to this:

```
 url(r'(?P<hsection>\w+)/(?P<section>\w+)/$', views.employee_listings, name='employee_listings'),
```

**You cannot mix kwargs and args** in one `{% 'url' %}` call.

Comment: Reverse for 'employee_listings' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'section': u'Employee Admin', u'hsection': u'Administration'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] 
didn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure? I interpreted that as not being able to mix it like this: `{% url 'employee_listings' hsection=hsection section %}`. Because in 1.8, I pass an argument to a url that is defined w/ named variables and it works just fine.

Comment: I'm sure, I did not mix it. I'm in Django 1.6.11